# how to remove the , and ; after keypress event in textbox jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating the tags on `,` and `;` and when a user writes something in the text box, I capture the event.

It looks something like this:

```
$("#txtTag").on("keypress", function (e) {
        var keypressed = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if ((keypressed == 59 || keypressed === 44)) {
            var tag = $(this).val().replace(",", "").replace(";", "");
            if ($("#tagsText").text() == "") {
                $("#tagsText").text(tag);
            }
            else {
                $("#tagsText").text($("#tagsText").text() + "," + tag);
            }
            $('#TagDiv').append("<li class='TagName'>" + tag + "<span class='deleteTag'>X</span></li>");
            $("#txtTag").val('');
            $("#txtTag").val().replace(",", "").replace(";", "");
        }

        e.preventdefault();
    });
```

but my problem is, when the tag is created, I want to clear the text box.

here is my live demo :http://jsfiddle.net/SMa9C/

Comment: I think that you post the wrong url to jsfiddle..

Comment: i changed the url, thanks

Comment: I am suggesting to use something that already exists (http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ see "Tagging" and "Plugins") and do not waste time researching new wheel.

Answer (score 3):

After clearing the text field you must prevent the default behaviour of the keypress event:

```
$(this).val('');
e.preventDefault();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SMa9C/22/)

Btw, remove the last line of your event handler; it has a typo which, when fixed, would actually prevent any characters from appearing in the text box.

Comment: Just as a complement, you can also replace `$("#txtTag").val('');` with `$(this).val('');`.

Answer (score 1):

Improved code , also handling the blank entry

```
$("#txtTag").on("keypress", function (e) {
    var keypressed = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ((keypressed == 59 || keypressed === 44)) {
        var tag = $(this).val().replace(",", "").replace(";", "");


        if (tag  != "")
        $('#TagDiv').append("<li class='TagName'>" + tag + "</li>");
        $(this).val('');
         return false ;
    }

});
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/SMa9C/21/